# Multiple input field search in PHP and MySQL not working

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have to enter multiple inputs (in pair) in one search:
for example:

```
1 Vorname and Strasse
2 Nachname and Strasse
3 Vorname and Email
4 Nachname and Email
5 Only Vorname
6 Only nickname
7 Only email
8 Vorname, Nachname, and Strasse
9 Vorname, Nachname, and Email
10 like that all separately and together
```

I did this below code and it's NOT WORKING for the above conditions. Somebody help me out with PHP/MySQL here. It would be really appreciated

PHP CODE:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) ){

    if(isset($_POST['text1'], $_POST['text7'])){
        // we got both vorname and ort 

        $statement= $myconnection->prepare(
                "SELECT * FROM OL_trans WHERE vorname = ? AND ort = ? OR nachname = ? OR strasse = ? OR email = ?");

        $statement->execute( [$_POST['text1'], $_POST['text7'], $_POST['text2'],$_POST['text8'], $_POST['text3']] ); 

    }
    else{
        if(isset($_POST['text1'])){
            // vorname
            $statement= $myconnection->prepare(
                "SELECT * FROM OL_trans WHERE vorname = ?");

            $statement->execute( [$_POST['text1']] ); 
        }
        if ( isset($_POST['text7'] )) {
            // ort 
            $statement= $myconnection->prepare(
                "SELECT * FROM OL_trans WHERE ort = ?");

            $statement->execute( [$_POST['text7']] ); 
        }
    }
    // generate the output
    $rows = $statement->fetchAll(); 

    foreach($rows as $row){ 
            echo '<br/>'.$row['vorname'].
           ' - '.$row['nachname'].

           ' - '.$row['strasse'].
           ' - '.$row['plz'].
           ' - '.$row['ort'].
           ' - '.$row['email'].
           ' - '.$row['telefon'].
           ' - '.$row['mobil'].'<br/><br/>';
           }    
}
```

HTML CODE:

```
<form method="post" action="sample.php">
    <br><br>
<br><br>
    <!--Beginn des Anrede-->
<div class="form1"><br><br>
<div class="names">
    <div class="anrede"> 
    <label for="Anrede">Anrede
        <select id="select" name="anrede" >
        <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
        <option value="herr">Herr</option>
        <option value="frau">Frau</option>
        <option value="andere">Andere</option>
        </select>
    </label></div>
    <br><br>
  <div><br>
    <label class="desc" id="title1" for="text1">Vorname</label>
    <div>
      <input id="text1" name="text1" type="text" class="field text fn" value="" size="8" tabindex="1" placeholder="vorname">
    </div>
  </div>
    <div><br><br>
    <label class="desc" id="title1" for="text2">Nachname</label>
    <div>
      <input id="text2" name="text2" type="text" class="field text fn" value="" size="8" tabindex="1" placeholder="Ihr Nachname">
    </div>
  </div>
    <div><br>
    <label class="desc" id="title1" for="text3">E-mail-Addresse</label>
    <div>
      <input id="text3" name="text3" type="text" class="field text fn" value="" size="8" tabindex="1" placeholder="Deine Email">
    </div>
  </div>
    <div><br>
    <label class="desc" id="title1" for="text4">Telefonnummer</label>
    <div>
      <input id="text4" name="text4" type="number" class="field text fn" value="" size="8" tabindex="1" placeholder="Deine Telefonnummer">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div><br><br>
    <label class="desc" id="title3" for="text5">
      Geburtstag
    </label>
    <div>
      <input id="text5" name="text5" type="date" spellcheck="false" value="" maxlength="255" tabindex="3"> 
   </div>
  </div>
 <div><br><br>
    <label class="desc" id="title3" for="text6">
      Plz
    </label>
    <div>
      <input id="text6" name="text6" type="number" spellcheck="false" value="" maxlength="255" tabindex="3" placeholder="Ihre Postleitzahl"> 
   </div><br><br>
   <label class="desc" id="title3" for="text7">
      Ort
    </label>
    <div>
      <input id="text7" name="text7" type="text" spellcheck="false" value="" maxlength="255" tabindex="3" placeholder="Dein Platz"> 
   </div><br><br>
  </div>

 <div>
    <label class="desc" id="title1" for="text8">Stra&szlig;e</label>
    <div>
      <input id="text8" name="text8" type="text" class="field text fn" value="" size="8" tabindex="1" placeholder="Deine Stra&szlig;e">
    </div>
  </div>

 <div><br><br>
    <label class="desc" id="title3" for="text9">
      Hausnummer
    </label>

      <input id="text9" name="text9" type="number" spellcheck="false" value="" maxlength="255" tabindex="3" placeholder="Ihre Hausnummer">

      <label class="desc" id="title3" for="text9">
      Hausnummerzusatz
    </label>
      <input id="text10" name="text10" type="number" spellcheck="false" value="" maxlength="255" tabindex="3" placeholder="Zus&#228;tzliche Adresse">
      <div><br><br>
      <div class="sub">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Suche">
      <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
      </div>
    <br><br><br></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

None of the pair searches is working. I tried changing between 'AND' & 'OR' and it just not working for me.

Comment: And what is not working? You have to be a bit more detailed.

Comment: No pairs of inputs are working, I tried changing "AND" & "OR" and still no changes.  Kindly, help me to get single and pair search function working.

Comment: Please... get rid of naming your variables like `text1  text2 ...text7`

Comment: How should I rewrite it then? I tried calling it the same and just not working too

Comment: something like `firstname, lastname ... city`

Comment: You are testing `if(isset($_POST['text1'], $_POST['text7']))` but then inside the IF using value in the Query that you dont know exist????

Comment: No, it doesn't work

Comment: I need the program to run like this:  Type first name and last name in City then SEARCH. it should print for example- Mitchell: Roy: Paris   Similarly, ANother search is Mitchell: Paris and another is Roy:Paris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all give your form fields sensible names so you know what you are dealing with when the fields get to PHP. For example at least the ones we are dealing with in the script:

was text1:

```
<input id="vorname" name="vorname" type="text" class="field text fn" value="" size="8" tabindex="1" placeholder="vorname">
```

was text7

```
<input id="ort" name="ort" type="text" spellcheck="false" value="" maxlength="255" tabindex="3" placeholder="Dein Platz">
```

was text2

```
<input id="nachname" name="nachname" type="text" class="field text fn" value="" size="8" tabindex="1" placeholder="Ihr Nachname">
```

was text8

```
<input id="strasse" name="strasse" type="text" class="field text fn" value="" size="8" tabindex="1" placeholder="Deine Stra&szlig;e">
```

was text3

```
<input id="email" name="email" type="text" class="field text fn" value="" size="8" tabindex="1" placeholder="Deine Email">
```

The PHP

```
// while developing and debugging add these
// just in case you are developing on a PHP configured for a LIVE env
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('log_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// this should really go in the db connect section
// will cause PDO to throw exceptions if errors happen in the PDO Code
// so you can actually see what the problems are

$myconnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if(isset($_POST['submit']) ){

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM OL_trans WHERE ';

    if ( !empty($_POST['vorname']) ) {
        $sql .= ' vorname = ? AND ';
        $params[] =  $_POST['vorname'];
    }   

    if ( !empty($_POST['nachname']) ) {
        $sql .= ' nachname = ? AND ';
        $params[] =  $_POST['nachname'];
    }

    if ( !empty($_POST['email']) ) {
        $sql .= ' email = ? AND ';
        $params[] =  $_POST['email'];
    }

    if ( !empty($_POST['strasse']) ) {
        $sql .= ' strasse = ? AND ';
        $params[] =  $_POST['strasse'];
    }

    if ( !empty($_POST['ort']) ) {
        $sql .= ' ort= ? AND ';
        $params[] =  $_POST['ort'];
    }

    // remove trailing AND

    $sql = rtrim($sql, 'AND ');
    $stmt = $myconnection->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($params);

    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

    foreach($rows as $row){ 
        echo '<br/>'.$row['vorname'].
       ' - '.$row['nachname'].

       ' - '.$row['strasse'].
       ' - '.$row['plz'].
       ' - '.$row['ort'].
       ' - '.$row['email'].
       ' - '.$row['telefon'].
       ' - '.$row['mobil'].'<br/><br/>';
    } 
}
```

> EDIT: RE Issues

I have a little test bed running, when I enter

```
$_POST = [  'submit' => 1, 
        'vorname' => 'Thomas', 
        'nachname' => 'Denly',
        'email' => 'xxxx@edfsd.com'
    ];
```

The query generated is

```
SELECT * FROM OL_trans WHERE  vorname = ? AND  nachname = ? AND  email = ?
```

And the `$params` array is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Thomas
    [1] => Denly
    [2] => xxxx@edfsd.com
)
```

If i enter

```
$_POST = [  'submit' => 1, 
        'vorname' => 'Thomas', 
        ];
```

The query is

```
SELECT * FROM OL_trans WHERE  vorname = ?
```

And parameters are

```
Array
(
    [0] => Thomas
)
```

**So what is wrong with that query and parameter values?**

Comment: Yeah, Because of the 'AND' i have to enter all coded fields mandatory. but i need a solution, when i enter only vorname or nachname (or any one field) it should also work

Comment: This should work for any 1 or any 2 or any 3 or any 4 or any 5 or these fields being entered? Can you echo the `$sql` from what does not work please.

Comment: Right now it's working for 5 fields. It's not working for any 1, any 2, any 3 and any 4 fields. I entered 'vorname', 'nachname', 'email', 'Strasse' and 'ort' and it works! When I remove any one or two or three or four field, its not working. The output is a blank page

Comment: PLEASE show me the `ECHO $sql; print_r($params);` for one situation where it does not work

Comment: No!, See i entered -> vorname:Thomas  nachname: Denly  email: xxxx@edfsd.com  strasse: 34 nordstr  Ort:Berlin. It prints the output successfully.  NOW! I also need it to work when i enter -> vorname:Thomas    Nachname:Denly    email:xxxx@edfsd.com. Similarly, any 2 or 3 fields i request it should work. Thanks a lot for your effort though

Comment: See in the above-edited code, I do not want to enter all the time 'vorname', 'nachname' and 'email' to search. Sometimes only 'vorname' or 'vorname with nachname'. I think because of 'AND', it's not working until entering all three fields

Comment: The QUERY only contains the COLUMN NAMES in the WHERE clause that relate to the Fields you enter in the FORM

Comment: Array ( [anrede] => [vorname] => thomas [nachname] => [email] => [telefonnummer] => [geburtstag] => [plz] => [ort] => [strasse] => [hausnummer] => [hausnummerzusatz] => [submit] => Suche )                                                        
  The prinr_r(POST)  generates this as output.